# How to dispatch action using router v6.4 and redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

Here is my code:

//main.jsx with router

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([{
    path: "/login",
    element: <LoginPage/>,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage/>,
    action: loginAction
},
{
    path: "*",
    element: <h1>404 Page not found...</h1>,
},]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <RouterProvider router={router}/>
        </Provider>
    </React.StrictMode>,)
```

//LoginPage.jsx

```
function LoginPage() {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return (
        <>
            <main>
                <LoginForm submitting={navigation.state === "submitting"}/>
            </main>
        </>
    )
}

export default LoginPage;

export async function action({request}) {
    //dispatch not possible
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const user = {
        username: formData.get("username"),
        password: formData.get("password")
    }

    try {
        await login(user);
    } catch (error){
        return error
    }

    return redirect('/');
}
```

//LoginForm.jsx

```
function LoginForm({submitting}) {
    return (
        <>
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <Form method={"post"} action={'/login'} className={classes.form}>
                    <h1>Ocean 4 HEALTH</h1>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label htmlFor={"username"}>Username</label>
                        <input id={"username"} name={"username"} type={"text"} required={true} minLength={5} maxLength={30}/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label htmlFor={"password"}>Password</label>
                        <input id={"password"} name={"password"} type={"password"} required={true} minLength={8} maxLength={30}/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <button disabled={submitting}>
                        {submitting ? "Submitting ..." : "Login"}
                    </button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

//login.js

```
    export async function login(user) {
//dispatch not possible
        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                codF: user.username.toUpperCase(),
                ...user
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": " application/json",
            },
        });
    
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw {message: "Ops, il login non è andato a buon fine", status: 500};
        }
        if (response.status === 226) {
            throw {message: "Ops, hai già una sessione aperta su un pc o su un altro tab...", status: 226};
        }
    
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(user));
    }
```

The problem/question:

How and where i can dispatch some action to send feedback to the user? I create a snackbar reducer for managing snackbar type, message and show (on, off) like this:

```
const snackbarSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'snackbar',
    initialState: {
        show: false,
        message: "",
        type: ""
    },
    reducers: {
        showSnackbar(state, action) {
            state.show = true;
            state.message = action.payload.message;
            state.type = action.payload.type;
        },
        removeSnackbar(state) {
            state.show = false;
        }
    }
})

export const snackbarActions = snackbarSlice.actions;

export default snackbarSlice
```

My goal is to dispatch showSnakbar if login succeed and an error message if there's an error.

Thanks in advance for the help. Any additional code or additional information I will be happy to give you

Comment: Use dispatch inside action in LoginPage isn't possible. Using dispatch inside my login service also doesn't work ... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the createAsynchThunk function provided in `redux-toolkit`:

```
export const login = createAsyncThunk(
    "user/login",
    async (user, ext) => {

        ext.dispatch(AnyActionYouWant1())
        ext.dispatch(AnyActionYouWant2())

        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}/auth/login`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                codF: user.username.toUpperCase(),
                ...user
            }),
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": " application/json",
            },
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw {message: "Ops, il login non è andato a buon fine", status: 500};
        }
        if (response.status === 226) {
            throw {message: "Ops, hai già una sessione aperta su un pc o su un altro tab...", status: 226};
        }

        sessionStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(user));
    }
)
```

You will also need to add the login function in `extraReducers`, you can do that by following [this guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers).

Another thing you need to keep in mind here is that `login` is now an action, so it needs to be `dispatched` to work.